# Unity - Activating "is Trigger" makes stuff fall through objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I am following this tutorial: https://www.mvcode.com/lessons/roll-a-ball-obstacle-course

At the very end we created enemies (cubes) and their movement works very good. But as soon as I activate "is Trigger" they fall through the plane into the void. What am I missing?

I tried to pull them above the floor to have some space between the bottom and the enemies, but they keep falling through the floor and only when I got "is Trigger" enabled.

thanks in advance,
Akuma

Comment: Thats what isTrigger does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that the cube is on top of the floor. When you enable "*Is Trigger*", collision is disabled and the cube would go through the floor.

The solution is to disable "*Use Gravity*" on the cube's `Rigidbody`.

[image]

Note that you are following a plagiarized version of the original *"Roll-a-ball tutorial"* tutorial which left out so many things. You should be following the original tutorial [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial). Watch the 10 seconds from [this](https://youtu.be/XtR29MmzuT0?t=894) video which  describes what you missed which is what I described above.

Comment: No it's the exact other way. "is Trigger" off = cube sitting perfectly on the ground, moving as intended. "is Trigger" on = cube falls through the floor. Gravity is checked.

Comment: That was a typo. I meant to say "enable" not "disable". Please try the answer before making further comments. That will prevent unnecessary comments.

Comment: Ah ok. Well then I'll just disable it again. As for the linked tutorial... I totally dislike video tutorials as it is a huge pain to re-view specific stuff as you can't just scroll or ctrl+f to back to something you wanted to reread... but also I CAN NOT view video tutorials as I am making this little thing in a medical rehab.

Comment: Well the tutorial you are following left that out and I think they will leave many other things out. You can scroll videos on Youtube videos by dragging the mouse over the timeline. You can fast-forward and re-wind too but since you don't like video tutorials, I don't think that would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to "scroll" through videos but it's still not a helpful thing, at least for my taste, when it comes to coding and stuff. :)

Comment: But if I need gravity?

Comment: If you are following the roll-ball tutorial I linked in my answer, you don't need gravity. Just follow the direction there.

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively (for those people who *want* or *need* gravity enabled on their cubes):

## Add a second collider.

[image: Two colliders, one box]

There's literally nothing stopping you from doing this.  You can make the trigger one bigger or just tweak the physics layers collision settings so that the collider keeping the enemies on the ground doesn't interfere with the operation of colliding with the player, etc.

Comment: The idea of making the cube a trigger is to make sure the player does not collide with the cube. The cube is like a coin in mario games. Imagine colliding with the coins. That would ruin the gameplay. The cube is also rotating. That would affect the rotation of the cube. Also, attaching multiple colliders to one gameobject  with different `IsTrigger` settings will  introduce hard to cure bugs. If you need to use many colliders, they should be child of the gameobject not attached directly to the gameobject. Finally, you should never attach the-same type of collider to the-same GameObject.

Comment: It really depends on the use-case. You can make the trigger volume larger than the collider volume (which only needs to be large enough to keep it from falling through the floor). As for "never attach the same type of collider to the same GO": I disagree. Unity *themselves* even point out that [using 3 box colliders for a rifle is much more performant than a single mesh collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/432/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html) and achieves comparable results: each one just has a different size and offset.

Comment: *"You can make the trigger volume larger than the collider volume (which only needs to be large enough to keep it from falling through the floor"* You don't understand. This won't work because *the cubes are spinning*. The cubes are meant to stay in one place but spin endlessly. If you do this and they touch the floor, they will move their position and it will also interfere with their spinning since they are colliding with the floor. Both of these we don't want in the gameplay.

Comment: *"Unity themselves even point out that using 3 box colliders for a rifle is much more performant than a single mesh collider and achieves comparable results"* This is called "Compound Colliders" and I agree with that. You don't understand my comment. You should not attach multiple colliders to the-same GameObject. You should put each collider as a child GameObject of that mesh. Don't attach several collides to the-same GameObject. Your answer is showing many colliders on one Object. This is wrong!

Comment: Quote from Unity *"To create a Compound Collider, create child objects of your colliding object, then add a Collider component to each child object."* By the way, [this](https://youtu.be/XtR29MmzuT0?t=894) is  the step OP missed.

Comment: @Programmer Multiple colliders on the same object are still valid. If they weren't, the engine would prevent it. It *used* to throw an "are you sure?" warning, but it doesn't any more.

Comment: I nearly gave up replying. This [post](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/188809/view.html) says the-same thing I just said but there is a comment that says that's no longer a problem. I doubt that comment. **Some** things in that answer is still true because I've answered several questions with this problem about 5 times between 2016 and today. I just looked for those answers I provided but couldn't find any of them. I am not talking about it being valid or not. I am saying that it will create problems/bugs. For example, the callback function getting called several times instead of once.